# Meteor - check() VS new SimpleSchema() for verifying .publish() arguments

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

To ensure the type of the arguments my publications receive, should I use SimpleSchema or `check()`?

```
Meteor.publish('todos.inList', function(listId, limit) {
  new SimpleSchema({
    listId: { type: String },
    limit: { type: Number }
  }).validate({ listId, limit });

  [...]
});
```

or

```
Meteor.publish('todos.inList', function(listId, limit) {
  check(listId, String);
  check (limit, Number);

  [...]
});
```

Comment: OK, but a fair part of the guide says otherwise

Comment: I use check on all arguments parsed to methods and publications, then simple-schema via collection2 on all DB operations.  Both have there place in my book.

Answer (score 6):

`check()` allows you to check data `type`, which is one thing, but is somewhat limited.

`SimpleSchema` is much more powerful as it checks all keys in a documents (instead of one at a time) and lets you define not only `type` but also allowed values, define default (or dynamic) values when not present.

You should use SimpleSchema this way:

```
mySchema = new SimpleSchema({ <your schema here>});

var MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("my_collection");
MyCollection.attachSchema(mySchema);
```

That way, you don't event need to check the schema in methods: it will be done automatically.
Of course it's always good practice to use the

`mySchema.validate(document);`

to validate a client generated document before inserting it in your collection, but if you don't and your document doesn't match the schema (extra keys, wrong types etc...) SimpleSchema will reject the parts that don't belong.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Just to be fair though, `Meteor.check()` also allows you [to check all the object properties in one go](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check).

Answer (score 4):

To check arguments to a `publish()` function or a `Meteor.method()` use `check()`. You define a `SimpleSchema` to validate inserts, upserts, and updates to collections. A publication is none of those - it's readonly. Your use of `SimpleSchema` with `.validate()` inline would actually work but it's a pretty unusual pattern and a bit of overkill.

You might find [this](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/12/meteor-security-no-4-extending-match.html) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit and to answer. I believe I understood the usefulness of `SimpleSchema()` for arguments validation now.

Answer (score 3):

**CHECK** is a lightweight package for argument checking and general pattern matching. where as SimpleSchema is a huge package with one of the **check** features. It is just that one package was made before the other.
Both works the same. You can use **CHECK** externally in Meteor.methods as well. Decision is all yours.

Answer (score 1):

Michel Floyd answer's, made me realize that `check()` actually sends `Meteor.Error(400, "Match Failed")` to the client, while `SimpleSchema` within `Methods` sends detailed `ValidationError` one can act upon [to display appropriate error messages on a form](http://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#method-form) for instance.

So to answer the question : should we use `check()` or `SimpleSchema()` to assess our arguments types in Meteor, I believe the answer is :

**Use `SimpleSchema` if you need a detailed report of the error from the client, otherwise `check()` is the way to go not to send back critical info.**